# SyntaxError: invalid syntax manage.py except ImportError as exc:

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created a django project called tictoctoe
but when I run "`py manage.py runserver`" it gives me following error.

```
File "manage.py", line 11
    except ImportError as exc:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

it used to work fine earlier.

here is

> manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tictactoe.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: which version of django and python you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your virtual environment is activated where you have Django installed.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out what was wrong,

I have created project directory inside the virtual environment, hence without activating the virtual environment it gives that error.

after I activating venv, py manage.py runserver works fine.

How to activate virtual environment:

```
my project location:
c:\Users\xyz\Documents\django-projects

my virtual environment location is 
c:\Users\xyz\Documents\django-projects\django-env

go to 
c:\Users\310227436\Documents\django-projects\django-env\Scripts 

invoke activate:
c:\Users\310227436\Documents\django-projects\django-env\Scripts> Activate
```

after doing this problem should be resolved.